# How to get the (PHP) code evaluation output displayed in Jenkins?

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration, static-analysis

I installed Jenkins and want to use it with the [PHP Quality Assurance Toolchain](http://phpqatools.org/).

I installed the PHP QA plugins ([Checkstyle](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin), [Clover PHP](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clover+PHP+Plugin), [JDepend](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JDepend+Plugin), [HTML Publisher](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) etc.) and configured the Ant `build.xml` file of the project.

Now I want to get the evaluations (of lint, PHP Depend including the generated graphical output, PHP Mess Detector, PHP Copy/Paste Detector, PHP_CodeSniffer, and PHPLOC) in Jenkins. Something like this:

[image]

But I don't see any navigation items for this or any possibility to configure the plugins, in order to get the wished output.

**How to get code analysis output in Jenkins?**

Answer (score 2):

The nice formatted code evaluation results appear in the navigation, after they have been added to the project (`{MyProject} -> Configure -> [section] Post-build Actions -> Add post-build action -> {action}`).

[image]